# Trying to connect to a sqlite but: SQL error or missing database (no such table: Bank_001)

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

I don't know what is wrong with this code; the SQL commands and the path looks  alright. The connect to the db is ok; but when I try to pass a simple search; it returns that that table doesn't exist.
I tried it (the same code) in a different method to add data and it works fine; so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your attention.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                First_GUI frame = new First_GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

    Connection conn = null;                   //Call the Connection Class from JavaSqlite Class

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public First_GUI() {
    conn = Sqlite_Connection.dbconnector();     //call the connection CONN from SQLite class, method DBconnector.
    setTitle("First GUI App");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout();
    flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel lblEnterTheName = new JLabel("Enter the Name :");
    lblEnterTheName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblEnterTheName.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    lblEnterTheName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    panel.add(lblEnterTheName);

    NameField = new JTextField();
    panel.add(NameField);
    NameField.setColumns(10);

    JButton Search = new JButton("Search");
    Search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // **************************************************************** 
    // Here is the PROBLEM.
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Bank_001 where AccountName like ?";
            try {
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, NameField.getText());
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }



        }
    });
    panel.add(Search);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);


}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the table Bank_001 actually exist in your database?

Comment: Yes!! There is a Table Bank_001 with 4 columns and  7 lines.

Comment: Does the database user your code uses have access to the table Bank_001?

Comment: The connection with the DB is done successfully ; but when I try to pass SQL codes, it can't find the table.

Answer (score 0):

can you show the code for this ?

```
conn = Sqlite_Connection.dbconnector();
```

are you using setURL() on a new SQLiteDataSource ?

assuming using setURL, is it constructed correctly ? 
Something like:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:sqlite-test.db"
```

Comment: It appears you do not have enough points to comment on a question, as this is less of an answer than a comment, requesting for more clarification

Comment: Hi dara, I've got it done already, it's working fine now, It was a problem in the middle of the code, a user in another forum helped me with that.  I'm gonna stick the whole code here. and thanks for asking.